# Converting .xib file to storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib

I have been searching how to convert a `xib` file into a `storyboard` file, but I can't find an answer, also I followed [this tutorial](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/window-uiviewcontroller-etc/storyboards/converting-old-apps-to-use-a-storyboard) but when I run the app the old `.xib` file is opened, no the new `storyboard`, my app has just two `.xib` files that I want to convert into `storyboards`, is there a way or tutorial at this date that can achieve that?

Comment: If you only have two xibs you can open them select the view controller, `Cmd+C`, open the Storyboard and `Cmd+V`. IBOutlets and IBActions will be lost but views and constraints will remain intact.

Answer (score 2):

You must update your target configuration of the app. Open the *General* tab. In the secion *Deployment Info* you will find *Main Interface*. Choose your storyboard instead of the XIB file.

Comment: Yes, I set my MainStoryboard (the new one) in that field, but xib file is getting presented. :(

Comment: This line was setting the xib as interface, `xViewController *xvc = [[xViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"xViewController" bundle:nil];` changed by `UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    xViewController *xvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"xViewController"];` Lets me set the storyboard as user interface